# Django Admin: Extra field added in model form can't be displayed for view permission

Tags: django, forms, view, permissions, admin

I have a problem about displaying an extra field (added from forms) for a model. When a user with all permissions on a model said Foo, the user can see the initial value for the extra field in admin page. But when a user has only view permission on the Foo model, he can't see the values of the extra field.

```
@admin.register(models.Foo)
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (('Foo', {'fields': ('extra_field'}))
    
    form = forms.FooForm
```

And in the forms:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['extra_field'].initial = 'extra_field'
```

If a user has all permissions on the Foo model, we can see in admin page:[image]

But if the user has only view permission on Foo model, he can't see nothing in this extra field:
[image]

In my case, I would like to see in `Extra field` the value: `extra_field`.
Can someone helps me please?

Answer (score 0):

If a user has only view permission, this user can only view added objects to database. If you save a foo with extra_field initial value "extra_field", the user will view this value from change-form via click the link from change-list of Foo object [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwBhb.jpg).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, this extra field is just used to show some information in the admin page and I don't want to declare this field in the Foo model. So if I save a foo with extra_field initial value "extra_field", this foo object will have extra field in the database? Can you show more about the way you do "save" a foo object?